# Create and upload pdf file to firebase storage using cloud functions? (can upload locally file, but not from cloud functions)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, pdfkit

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage({
keyFilename: "./xxx-path-to-key(locally).json",
projectId: "my project ID",
});

exports.get_data = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

const pdf = async () => {
const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.text("Hello, World!");
doc.end();
return await getStream.buffer(doc);
};

const pdfBuffer = await pdf();
const pdfBase64string = pdfBuffer.toString("base64"); //getting string which I want to send to storage like pdf file

const bucketName = "gs://path-to-storage.com/"
let filename = "test_file.pdf" //some locally pdf file (but can't save locally while using cloud functions) 

const uploadFile = async () => {
// Uploads a local file to the bucket
await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, { //this one fine works for locally uploading
  metadata: {
    cacheControl: "public, max-age=31536000",
    contentType: "application/pdf",
  },
});

console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
};

uploadFile();

})
```

I need to create PDF file using cloud functions and upload it to firebase storage.
I've create pdfBase64string - and just need to save this string-pdf to storage, but can't find information to do it.
I tried many different ways but got stuck, because Google answers come to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are using the **Cloud Storage** and not the **Firebase Storage** library. You can upload with:

```
// Create a root reference
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
// Create a reference to 'mountains.pdf'
var ref = storageRef.child('mountains.pdf');
// Base64 formatted string
var message = '5b6p5Y+344GX44G+44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
ref.putString(message, 'base64').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a base64 string!');
});
```

from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string)

Now,

1. To be able to access Firebase Storage from **Cloud Functions** you need to add Firebase Editor role to the Cloud Function service account.
2. Alternatively you can use a **Firebase Function** [to upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions) to Firebase Storage.

The Cloud Storage library is not the same as the Firebase Storage library.

Comment: If you are still having issues, please include the error and trace given.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answer, it almost done, but still have another error "String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found (storage/invalid-format)"
`var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var ref = storageRef.child("file.pdf");
const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.text("Hello, World!");
doc.end();
const pdfBuffer = await getStream.buffer(doc);
const pdfBase64string = pdfBuffer.toString("base64");
ref
    .putString(pdfBase64string, "base64", { contentType: "application/pdf" })
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      console.log("Uploaded a base64 string!")
    })`

Comment: I found a related [GitHubIssue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/576) which you might find helpful.